# parse XML and insert data in MySQL table

Tags: javascript, mysql, xml

I am trying to parse a xml file that i have (using javascript DOM). and then i want to insert this data in a mysql table (using php).

I know how to parse xml data. But i am unable to figure out how to use php and javascript together and insert data in mysql table.

Kindly help me in this.

Best
Zeeshan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use [PHP DOM](http://au.php.net/book.dom) to parse the XML ?

e.g:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('book.xml');
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

After loaded your document `$doc` you can use the PHP DOM functions.

Comment: I would love to use php dom. it will make things so very easy to do right?
can you please give me a few sample, where i can learn about how to parse xml in php dom.

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript needs to send the data to the server. There are several ways this can be achieved.

1. Generate a form and submit it
2. Use [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html) directly
3. Use a library like [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui.) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Once there, you get the data (from $_POST for example) and [insert it into MySQL as normal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: this is stupid of me, but can you tell me how should i make a form that has all my xml parsed data, and then which i can submit to php on server so that it can insert each record of my xml in a table

Comment: var form = document.createElement('form'); form.action='foo.php'; form.method="post"; var data1 = document.createElement('input'); data1.value = myVar; data1.name="data1"; form.appendChild(data1); document.body.appendChild(form); form.submit(); /* Simplified of course */

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to do this, for example:

```
<house>
 <roof>as</roof>


<door>asd</door><window number="12">iles</window></house>
```

$('path_to_xml',xml).each(function(){
    roof = $('roof',this).text();
    door = $('door',this).text();
    num_wind = $('window',this).attr('number');
});